# How to change scale of x axis, when the x variable is a character?

Tags: r, ggplot2

thanks for looking at the question.

Sample code -

```
    library('tidyverse')
    
 df <- data.frame('Time' = c(10,20,5,25,10), 'Date' = c("2023-01-01 11:43:02",
"2023-01-01 12:05:07","2023-01-01 14:43:02","2023-01-02 11:43:02",
"2023-01-02 13:43:02"))
    
    
df <- df %>%  separate(Date, c('Date', 'Hour'), sep = " ")
    
    
df %>% 
ggplot() +
geom_col(aes(x = Hour, y = Time)) +
facet_wrap(~Date)
```

How do I change the x axis limits for a character variable? I have tried `xlim()` and converted the variable to numeric. However, this does not work. I am not sure if I have to keep the variable `Date` as it was, and don't separate it. Maybe I can adjust the limits like that, but I have tried and failed. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Keep datetime as datetime, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36460980/680068

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion on how to work this with. First and foremost, I think you should work with the x-axis as a `POSIXt` variable using ggplot's `scale_x_datetime`. This will keep it number-like instead of ordinal, which gives you some flexibility.

Create a `Date`-like column that keeps the date portion itself unchanged (all the same day-of-year) and varies the time-of-day:

```r
df %>%
  separate(Date, c("Date", "Hour"), sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(Date1 = as.POSIXct(paste(first(Date), Hour)))
#   Time       Date     Hour               Date1
# 1   10 2023-01-01 11:43:02 2023-01-01 11:43:02
# 2   20 2023-01-01 12:05:07 2023-01-01 12:05:07
# 3    5 2023-01-01 14:43:02 2023-01-01 14:43:02
# 4   25 2023-01-02 11:43:02 2023-01-01 11:43:02
# 5   10 2023-01-02 13:43:02 2023-01-01 13:43:02
```

Note how the date portion is always `"2023-01-01"` regardless of what day-of-year the real data is on. We're not discarding the date, we're just setting the x-axis (time of day) to be contained within the same 24 hour period, while allowing you to have the `Date` itself untouched.

```r
df %>%
  separate(Date, c("Date", "Hour"), sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(Date1 = as.POSIXct(paste(first(Date), Hour))) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = Date1, y = Time)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Date, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H:%M:%S")
```

[image: ggplot with datetime x-axis]

With this option, you can control the x-axis with `POSIXt`-class arguments, such as

```r
# should do this programmatically instead of static strings ...
xlimits <- as.POSIXct(paste("2023-01-01", c("00:00:00", "23:59:59")))
df %>%
  separate(Date, c("Date", "Hour"), sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(Date1 = as.POSIXct(paste(first(Date), Hour))) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = Date1, y = Time)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Date, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H:%M:%S", limits = xlimits)
```

[image: ggplot with xlim changed]

The end result of shifting to using a `POSIXt` continuous value on the x-axis is that limits become fluid to control, and we can use `date_labels=` to very specifically control how it is displayed (e.g., `date_labels="%H"` or `="%H:%M"` if you want hour or hour-minute labels). And since we're no longer dealing with ordinal data, the lateral separation between bars is now consistent (not necessarily true with ordinal data).

Comment: Thank you Sir. I'm working through your solution. However, in my real data, geom_col does not graph all the data points.  Many are missing.  Even if I use  facet_grid() with another variable , to check they are not overlapping on the graph, many bars are still missing. However, if I change it to geom_point all the data points are shown. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks                                                                         *Edit* - To clarify there are many more data points in the real data I'm using

Comment: I understand that your real data is more complex and has missingness. I cannot reproduce the whole thing going away, so there must be something else going on. Please update your sample data to reflect the situation you are seeing.

Comment: I have been increasing the width of the bars and this seems to resolve the problem. Thank you

Comment: I am using ggplotly() with this graph. Therefore, the first date always appears when I hover over the graph at each data point. For example, a data point would say - 2023-01-01 13:43:02 , when it is in the 2023-01-02 section. Do you have any advice please? Thank you

Comment: I have fixed the issue. Thank you Sir