Adding hours to Shiny graph x axis
I would like my plot to show hours in between the days so I can identify more detail. I'm not sure how to acheive this
The data looks like:

the graph looks like

The Plot code
  # plot time series
  output$Plot <- renderPlot({
      dataset <- f()
      ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Date, y=`MeanScore`)) +
        geom_line(size=2) +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = 'black', angle = 90,
                                         size = 13, hjust = 0.5, vjust =
                                           0.5),axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
        ylab("Temp") +
        theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = 'black', size = 12),
              axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12,
                                          hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.2)) +
        theme(strip.text.y = element_text(size = 11, hjust = 0.5,
                                          vjust = 0.5, face = 'bold')) 
  })``` 


Take a look at a question like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460980/ggplot-x-axis-as-date-with-hours. You'll want to add a scale_x_datetime with the right breaks for your purposes. This is really just a ggplot thing; it doesn't have anything to do with shiny.
